# Error clicking in the hr_attendance icon in odoo 9

Tags: odoo, odoo-9

When I click on the hr_attendance icon, this message appears:

```
The operation cannot be completed, probably due to the following:
- deletion: you may be trying to delete a record while other records still reference it
- creation/update: a mandatory field is not correctly set
[object with reference: employee_id - employee.id]
```

Going to the attendance.js, I put a lot of console.logs and I realized that inside the 'do_update_attendance' function, the variable self.employee_id is undefined, but this is the official code (I didn't changed anything).

Is this a bug or I have to modify some code?

Comment: With what user did you test this?

Comment: @CZoellner I tested it with the administrator user and with another user created without privileges

Comment: i've tested it on latest possible odoo 9 [runbot](http://runbot.odoo.com) with admin and demo (demo has to be configured for attendances) and it worked without problems.

Comment: @CZoellner That's true, in runbot works perfectly. I just have done a git pull from odoo9 repository in a new instance, but now the icon (the arrow and the box) doesn't appear. What modules/configuration I have to add/modify in order to see the icon?

Comment: @MouTio have you altered the records in the database?

Comment: @danidee, yes. Not me, but the records in the database have been altered by the old administrator. What should I modify (in the database or in the code) to get this working fine?

Comment: From experience i've noticed that this is always a database `Integrity error`, but it's not always the case, when you hit the button the next time and the error comes up, check the server logs and paste them here for us to see

Comment: @MouTio you need to set "Attendances" under user accesses to see the little button on an user

Comment: @danidee :
INFO mydb requests.packages.urllib3.connectionpool: Starting new HTTPS connection (1): api.ipify.org
INFO mydb openerp.sql_db: bad query: INSERT INTO "hr_attendance" ("id", "action", "employee_id", "ip_address", "name", "create_uid", "write_uid", "create_date", "write_date") VALUES(nextval('hr_attendance_id_seq'), NULL, NULL, '212.170.199.23', '2016-08-24 06:57:51', 1, 1, (now() at time zone 'UTC'), (now() at time zone 'UTC')) RETURNING id
INFO mydb werkzeug: 192.168.1.44 - - [24/Aug/2016 06:57:52] "POST /web/dataset/call_kw/hr.employee/attendance_action_change HTTP/1.1" 200 -

Comment: @CZoellner In Settings > Users > Access Rights, the option of "Attendances" is checked. You mean this?

Comment: @danidee if you preffer, here is more friendly:
http://pastebin.com/rgmEaz5p

Comment: employee_id on the INSERT is NULL, i bet it's a required field because the would be logical. I think you need to set an employee on the user itself or you need to set a user on an employee to use this feature.

Comment: @CZoellner that's it!! Now it works. Thank you very much :)
I am going to post the solution

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fixed it doing these steps for a new user:

1. Log in as administrator
2. Employees > Employees > Create button (Fill the name)
3. Select the "HR Settings" tab > Related User -> Create and edit (Fill the name and email).
4. Save the user and save the employee.
5. Go to Developer mode (User menu > About > Activate the developer mode)
6. Settings > User > Select the new created user > Edit > Mark the option "Attendances"
7. Save the user.

Now it works :)

Comment: glad you got it to work!....always look at the logs, there's a lot of helpful information there that the errors in the UI don't show you